# MPICH2 Unable to Connect in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, mpi, mpich

whenever i try command mpiexec -n 4 testmpi.exe

> Unable to connect to 'RIJDZUAN-PC:8676', sock error: generic socket
>   failure, error stack: MPIDU_Sock_post_connect(1200): unable to connect
>   to RIJDZUAN-PC on port 8676, ex hausted all endpoints (errno -1)
>   MPIDU_Sock_post_connect(1247): unable to connect to RIJDZUAN-PC on
>   port 8676, No  connection could be made because the target machine
>   actively refused it. (errno  10061)

and when i try to smpd -install or smpd -start giving me

> OpenSCManager failed: Access is denied. (error 5)

i believe i'd already registering mpiexec over mpiexec -register

how to resolve this?

Comment: You are missing administrative rights while installing `smpd`. You should open a command prompt with administrative rights or temporary switch off UAC.

Comment: i've already use the admin profile and turn it off UAC,the problem still there

Answer (score 3):

I got this message as well. Turns out when the installer says "successful" but smpd is not running, then the install is silently incorrect.

Copied (and slightly altered) from [here](http://lists.mcs.anl.gov/pipermail/mpich-discuss/2011-April/009694.html)

1. Uninstall previous version of MPICH2
2. Open an admin command prompt by right-clicking on the command prompt icon and selecting "run as administrator"
3. Run "msiexec /i mpich2-1.3.2p1-win-ia32.msi" from the admin command prompt to install MPICH2
4. During installation select that MPICH2 be installed for "Everyone" for all users.
5. Run wmpiconfig and store username/password. EDIT: Use your REAL windows login name and password.
6. Add "C:\Program Files\MPICH2\bin" to system Path and EDIT: no need to reboot
7. Check smpd using 'smpd -status'. it should return 'smpd running on $hostname$'
8. To test execution environment, go to the directory $MPICHROOT\examples and run cpi.exe using: 'mpiexec -n 4 cpi'

You can follow the above steps even if you are not logged in as an admin user. Just make sure to follow step 2 closely. If you see

```
OpenSCManager failed: Access is denied
```

It probably means you are not on an admin command prompt. If step 7 checks out, you should be good to go.

Answer (score 1):

run CMD as an admin, and after words run the smdp -install comand.